# Comparison between argv[1] and string in C programming

Tags: c, or-operator

I wrote some code where I try to compare the argv[1] with the string `"o"` and the string `"m"` and print an error if I don't find it in argv[]. The problem is, that the program doesn't work as expected. This is what I have done:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if((strcmp(argv[1], "o") != 0) || (strcmp(argv[1], "m") != 0))
  {
    printf("error\n");
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: @Martina It is unclear whether you are trying to check whether the string argv[1] contain either character '0' or 'm' or the string is equal to either the string "o" or "m".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your check

```
if((strcmp(argv[1], "o") != 0) || (strcmp(argv[1], "m") != 0))
{
    printf("error\n");
}
```

Can be translated in

> Raise an error if the first argument of the program IS NOT equal to 'o' **AND** at the same time IS NOT equal to 'm'

(in fact, `strcmp ()` returns 0 when the compared strings are equal)

The only possible way to avoid the error would be that the argument is equal to 'o' and to 'm' **at the same time**. Which is obviously impossible.

You have two options. First you can perform a *positive check*:

```
if((strcmp(argv[1], "o") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[1], "m") == 0))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    printf("error\n");
}
```

Or a negative check (like yours). In this case you need that the argument is not 'o' AND it is NOT 'm' (logic operator `&&`):

```
if((strcmp(argv[1], "o") != 0) && (strcmp(argv[1], "m") != 0))
{
    printf("error\n");
}
```