# Accessing the structure's array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure, declaration

I'm working on an assignment in c programming and have some understanding difficulties.
I've created a function that should create a folder or a file (with string only.)
In case the new object is a folder, I want to enter the number of subfiles, recursively.

The question: How do I accessing the subfiles in case I want to work with the data of the second file (only string)? (and also accessing subfolders).

File structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;                    //name of File
    char type;                    // 'f' - data file, 'd'-folder.
    union {
        char data[5];             //f -80 chars array for content of file.
        struct {                //d -arry of pointers to 'File' Files.
            struct File ** files;
            unsigned int size;
        }folder;
    }content;
}File;
```

The function:

```
File * newFile(char type)
{
    File *pfile = (File*)malloc(sizeof(File)); //creating new File
    if (!pfile) {
        printf("No memory for new file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (type != 'f' || type != 'd') { // in case of wrong input of type.
        while(type != 'f' && type !='d'){
        printf("Wrong input,try again: ");
        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        type =getchar();
        }
    }
    printf("Enter File name: ");
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    char name[NAME];
    gets(name);
    pfile->name = name;
    if (type == 'f') {      // New File is 'folder'
        pfile->type = 'f';
        //fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        printf("Enter number of files in %s: ",pfile->name);

        scanf(" %d", &pfile->content.folder.size);
        if (pfile->content.folder.size == 0) { // Zero files in the folder
            pfile->content.folder.files = NULL; // No more files / empty folder
        }
        pfile->content.folder.files = (File**)malloc(pfile->content.folder.size * sizeof(File));
        if (!pfile->content.folder.files) {
            printf("No memory for sub files\n");
            exit(2);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pfile->content.folder.size; ++i) { // creates 'size' file per folder
            fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
            printf("(%d):Enter type of file (d-folder,f-file): ", i + 1);

            pfile->content.folder.files[i] = newFile(getchar());
        }
        return pfile;

    }
    else if (type == 'd') { //File creation
        pfile->type = 'd';
        printf("Enter file's text:\n");
        scanf(" %s", &pfile->content.data);
    }
    return pfile;
```

Comment: It looks to me that you swapped `f` and `d` in your logic

Comment: Your condition `if (type != 'f' || type != 'd') ` is not probably what you want, as it will always be true. It is a common mistake: I explained a similar mistake just [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176218/11336762).

Comment: Thank you for the pin point. it was fixed.

Comment: But my issue is accessing subfiles. how should be the syntax?

Comment: @DanShar I'm happy to help. I know that it wasn't the core of your problem;  that's because I didn't write an answer. About your problem, it is honestly not clear to me: first of all I don't know ehat a _subfile_ is, than I would need a complete example (a minimum program with a `main` calling your `newFile()` function, with an example of input, the expected output and the actual one).

Comment: Thanks for the serious attention.
I'll raise a new question with a simpler and more specific explanation about my issue.

Comment: regarding: `File * newFile(char type)` and similar statements:  The `File` needs to be ALL CAPS