# Loop to check whether one of two characters was entered runs forever

Tags: c, while-loop, logical-operators

i am trying to make a code that will print "Yayy" after i press the right key (m or o) but i am stucked in while function ... i can press anything and it will still ask me to press somethig..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char input_char;
    printf("Press a key:");
    input_char = getc(stdin);
    printf("You pressed:%c\n", input_char);

    while (input_char != 'm' || input_char != 'o') {
        printf("Press a key:");
        input_char = getc(stdin);
        input_char = getc(stdin);
        printf("You pressed:%c\n", input_char);
    }
    printf("Yayyy");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison between argv\[1\] and string in C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175860/comparison-between-argv1-and-string-in-c-programming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about this check:

```
while (input_char != 'm' || input_char != 'o') {
```

This says "loop while `input_char` isn't `m` or `input_char` isn't `o`." But if you think about it, *every* character either isn't `m` or isn't `o`. (Do you see why?) As a result, this will loop forever.

To fix this, change the loop to read

```
while (input_char != 'm' && input_char != 'o') {
```

which says "loop as long as the input isn't `m` *and* the input isn't `o`." That way, if the input was `m` or the input was `o`, the loop stops running. (Do you see why?)

One other small fix - there's no reason to call `getc` twice inside the loop. That reads two characters, but you'll only remember one of them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx very much.. i feel so stupid now :D i was looking at it like for 2 days and couldnt figure it out :D *facepalm*

Comment: No worries! This is a *very* common mistake for programmers to make. So pat yourself on the back for having learned enough coding to even make this mistake, make a note of it for the future, and best of luck!

Comment: And also i call getc twice inside the loop bcs the fist getc in my code will leave "\n" after i press enter... so i needed to get rid out of it. Probably the solution for this should be something like this scanf("%*[^\n])

Answer (score 3):

You want the user to press m or o, thus the loop should run while the input isn't m and isn't o. You need to change this line:

`while (input_char != 'm' || input_char != 'o')`

To this:

`while (input_char != 'm' && input_char != 'o')`